# Why when promise calling another promise return 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

in my application i work with mongoose and mongodb , in one scenario i need to calling promise from another promise, but promise return undefined, my code is

```js
function first (num) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(num % 2 === 0){
      resolve(num);
    }
    else{
      reject('Error Happend');
    }
  })
}


function second(num){
 first(num).then(function(res){
   return res;
 }).catch(function(err){
   return err;
 })
}

console.log(second(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.js"></script>
```

in this case i pass `2` to `second` function and i want it return 2 but it return undefined, i search on SF and find some topic about this but nothing of them solve my problem.

Comment: `second` does not `return` anything? All your `return` statements are in some callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi , thanks , how to solve this to `return`

Comment: You cannot. Promises are asynchronous. All you can do is return a new promise (constructed by calling `then` or `catch`), and then use `second(2).then(console.log)` in the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logging the return value of `second(2)`, but the `second` function has no `return` statement in it, so it will always return `undefined`.

Note that the function expressions you pass to `then` and `catch` (which do have `return` statements are not the `second` function itself).